# Objects being created from a txt file with the wrong attribute types?

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes, init

I have a txt file that is formatted (P001, Part001, 10.0, 100 OR AP002, AssembledPart2, 130, 1, P002, P004) which is being read line by line, each line being created as an object. It all seems to work fine, but all the attributes are being set to str, and I need some of them to be float or int. I can't figure out why this is happening.

```
def readParts(self, file):
    '''Reads the parts.txt file and runs it line by line thru part.__init__ and adds to parts list
    '''
    id = None
    name = None
    price = 0.0
    onhandqty = int
    componentID1 = None
    componentID2 = None
    with open(os.path.join(sys.path[0],"parts.txt"), "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            row = line.split(",")
            if len(row) == 4:
                id, name, price, onhandqty = [i.strip() for i in row]
                part = Part(id, name, price, onhandqty)
                WarehouseManager.parts.append(part)
            if len(row) == 6:
                id, name, price, onhandqty, componentID1, componentID2 = [i.strip() for i in row]
                assembledpart = AssembledPart(id, name, price, onhandqty, componentID1, componentID2)
                WarehouseManager.parts.append(assembledpart)
```

For reference, the Class **init**

```
class Part():

    id = None

    name = None

    price = 0.0

    onhandqty = int



    def __init__(self, id, name, price, onhandqty):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.onhandqty = onhandqty
```

```
class AssembledPart(Part):
    

    componentID1 = None

    componentID2 = None



    def __init__(self, id, name, price, onhandqty, componentID1, componentID2):
        super().__init__(id, name, price, onhandqty)
        self.componentID1 = componentID1
        self.componentID2 = componentID2
```

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you `print(type(onhandqty))` where you're passing it into the `Part` constructor, you'll see that it's a `str`. If you want it to be an `int` in the `Part` object then you need to cast it before passing it into the constructor.

Setting `onhandqty = int` in the class does not force a passed-in value to be `int`